# Mark of the Ninja - statistics number of death?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

Is there any statistics about number of deaths main character in Mark of the Ninja or not? Can we always repeat any level and get more points in any time we want? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the death count.

Yes, you can replay levels to try and beat your previous performances, leaderboards and for Steam achievements.